# How to Invoke/Open html widget on button/icon click in ibook author?

Tags: html, ibook-author

In iBook Author I have an HTML widget which I want to open when a button is clicked from a page.

Is there a possibility of that?

Answer (score 1):

use an image which looks like a button, instead of your default preview or preview image. on click it will open your html widget ...